# How can I grab data from a .txt file using the csv module while accounting for potential blank fields?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am currently trying to grab useful data from a machine that spits out logs in the form of text files. The relevant data I am trying to get are Dimensions A, B, and C, Radius Left and Right, Tolerance Left and Right, and the units.

[image]

[image]

However, as you can see, sometimes the fields are empty. Currently, I use the string split function to separate the string by whitespace and assign from there.

```
self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension A"] = ((strow.split())[1])
self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension B"] = ((strow.split())[2])
self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension C"] = ((strow.split())[3])
self.variables.jobDetails["Radius Left"] = ((strow.split())[4])
self.variables.jobDetails["Radius Right"] = ((strow.split())[5])
```

However, the problem with this is that if some of the fields are blank, it skips over them and assigns them the wrong dictionary keys. If my code is used on the log in the second image, the Left Radius number of 1 would incorrectly be assigned to `self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension A"]`.

Looking through all the logs, it seems that the last digit of the field entries are always in the same spot. Hopefully this helps.

Thanks

Comment: It seems your file is not really comma-separated data, but rather fixed-width data. Have you considered pulling out the fixed-width columns (`int(strow[10:20])` or whatever) instead of using the `csv` module?

Comment: @WanderNauta Never heard of that! I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the code is that you are using `split()`. That splits up your data on whitespace. It doesn't know the difference between whitespace that separates fields and whitespace that represents an empty field.

The only option is to work out how wide each field is. It's hard to do this accurately with only a picture of the output but it seems to me you have a line of 90 characters split into fields of width 9, 9, 9, 13, 8, 15, 11, 16; of which all but the last is either blank or numeric.

You don't say but I am guessing that you already are picking the correct row out of the data and storing it in `strow`.

So:

```
def pick_apart(strow):
   spans =((0, 9), (9, 18), (18, 27), (27, 40), (40, 48), (48, 63), (63, 74), (74, 90))  
   # you will have to double-check this, it's nearly impossible to get right by eye alone
   return list(strow[i:j] for (i,j) in spans)

# This line emulates your process of reading the data into strow
strow = "        0       40       40            1       1              3          3           g-in"
fields = pick_apart(strow)
# If this assertion fails then there are errors in spans that you need to fix
assert (fields==['        0', '       40', '       40', '            1', '       1', '              3', '          3', '           g-in'])


self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension A"] = fields[0]
self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension B"] = fields[1]
self.variables.jobDetails["Dimension C"] = fields[2]
self.variables.jobDetails["Radius Left"] = fields[3]
self.variables.jobDetails["Radius Right"] = fields[4]
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, worked perfect. I added a `.strip()` at the end of each `fields[i]` to get rid of the whitespace. Thanks a lot!!